# plotnine geom_boxplot ignores required aesthetic and requires unnecessary aesthetic

Tags: python, python-ggplot, plotnine

I have data that looks like:

```
Scenario        ymin         lower        middle         upper      ymax
One     16362.586379  20911.338893  27121.693254  35219.449009  46406.087619
Two     19779.003240  25390.096116  33108.174561  43545.202225  58464.277060
```

Rather than use *all* 50 k data points for every Scenario (there are many more than One and Two), I've computed the positions I need for the box and whiskers.

I try to plot this via

```
import pandas
import plotnine as p9

df = pandas.read_excel('boxplot_data.xlsx', sheet='Sheet1')
gg = p9.ggplot()
gg += p9.geoms.geom_boxplot(mapping=p9.aes(x='Scenario', ymin='ymin', lower='lower', middle='middle', upper='upper', ymax='ymax'), data=df, color='k', show_legend=False, inherit_aes=False)
gg += p9.themes.theme_seaborn()
gg += p9.labels.xlab('Scenario')
gg.save(filename='scenario_boxplot.png', dpi=300)
```

The documentation at https://plotnine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/plotnine.geoms.geom_boxplot.html#plotnine.geoms.geom_boxplot indicates that the geom_boxplot line of code supplies the required aesthetic parameters to define the box and whiskers.

Running this, however, gives

> plotnine.exceptions.PlotnineError: 'stat_boxplot requires the
>   following missing aesthetics: y'

Why is **stat_boxplot** being called, with *its* required aesthetics, not **geom_boxplot**?

And more importantly, does anybody know how to correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `geom_boxplot` with `stat_boxplot` instead of `stat_identity`.

```py
geom_boxplot(stat='identity', ...)
```

Comment: That works, many thanks. I don't understand why, though. If I wanted to use `stats.stat_boxplot`, wouldn't I just use _it_?

Comment: geoms and stats have independent requirements. By default, geoms and stats are paired so that the `stat` computes the requirements of the `geom`, so the user has to only provide the requirements of the `stat`. If you choose to provide the requirements of the `geom`, then you have to ignore the default `stat` for that `geom`. That is what `stat_identity` is for i.e pass through the user mappings directly to the `geom`.